# Is there only a single Throne of Heroes in the entire Type-Moon multiverse?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero, fate-series

Is it ever specified that whether each alternate timeline has a ToH of its own, or there is only a single ToH in the entire Type-Moon multiverse?

Comment: i think it's implied that there's only the one because EMIYA comes from an alternate Timeline when he was summoned. one would then ask what happens in alternate timelines which all created EMIYA but funny thing is that there doesn't seem to be any known timelines where that might be possible. Fate/Apocrypha could be the closest since the Einzberns still continue with the Fuyuki Ritual even after loosing the Greater Grail however without Angra Mainyu corrupting it to then cause the great fire in the 4th war would Shirou still get adopted by Kiritsugu and have the same ideals?

Answer (score 1):

The Throne of Heroes exists outside of the world and the time axis. This interpretation is taken from Fate/complete material III: World material - Records of Heavens Feel - Servant System: Difference between Heroic Spirits and Servants, p.012, you can check a fan-translation from that excerpt [here](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Heroic_Spirit#cite_note-CM3Diff-1). So there's only ONE Throne of Heroes, which is linked to the Root which is also cut off from the world and the time axis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single Throne of Heroes for the entire multiverse (Kaleidoscope), which is why you can have different aspects of the same heroic spirit.

Comment: Kaleidoscope is Second Magic, which is said to allow movement through parallel worlds. The Throne of Heroes exists outside time and space. See  *Fate/complete material III: World material* - Records of Heavens Feel - Servant System.

Comment: The existence of Kaleidoscope is what makes the Nasuverse a multiverse instead of a single world line system like say, Steins Gate. There is 1 Throne of Heroes for the multiverse.

Comment: The answer makes it sound as if Kaleidoscope IS the multiverse, which is wrong per se. The Nasuverse is a multiverse despite the existence of Kaleidoscope, what the 2nd Magic does is make it observable and lets you travel through the parallel worlds. Saying that it's Kaleidoscope what makes it a multiverse is like saying that if microscopes didn't exist cells wouldn't be real.